# I need to create a random dataset for 5 rows in excel (avoiding duplicates)

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, dataset

I'm working on cleaning and structuring an Excel dataset containing rates for customers on different periods and from Point A to Point B which I will import into a final sheet. There are 4 columns
[image: Like here]

The first row has 5 sets of dates, Second row has 68 different locations, Third row has 10 locations and fourth has 2 customers.

I need to generate a matrix with a random combination of these 4 columns. I might have been pretty bad at statistics, but I tried to create this set manually (copy+paste) to get a total of 6800 rows (68 times 10 times 5 times 2), but when I concatenated them and ran conditional formatting, and there were duplicates.

Does anyone have an idea of randomizing this sample perfectly without duplicates? I need a function to be able to generate this sample. No macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with some manual copy + paste and TEXTJOIN function.

I had 6800 combinations (68x5x10x2), which I created in Excel, then I used the function

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A1,B1,C1,D1)
```

This gave me the result as Date1;A;B;Cust1 in column 5. I used Remove duplicates to get unique Textjoins. I had 5440 remaining after completing this step.

Then I separated these unique values into columns using Text-to-column function.